# How to run scala jar with java libraries?

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, jar

I need to create a scala application which uses several java library jars ( these jars are only available in java). For this, I created a Scala Project using Scala version (scala-sdk-2.13.0-M4 with Java 1.8.0_162) on IntelliJ Idea (Ver. 2018.1.6 community). Added an artifact as jar. It uses several java library jar files as well.

I need to run my scala jar on scala version 2.12.6

Case 1 : When I create the scala jar file of my code only and keep other jars in a lib folder adjacent to MyScalaJar.jar file and run command

```
    scala -classpath lib / *.jar MyScalaJar.jar

    It gives below exception:

java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.$anonfun$tryClass$1(ScalaClassLoader.scala:45)
```

.
.
.
            at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:101)
            at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)

```
Case 2 : 
When I create one consolidated jar file MyFullScalaJar.jar using option "Extract Jar" and run command:

scala MyFullScalaJar.jar
```

It gives Exception like missing log4j jar: 
I've checked that contents of log4j jar are there in the consolidated jar file as extracted in it.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

.
.
.
.            at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:96)
            at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:101)
            at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)

I must be missing something very basic. What is the correct way to create/run scala jar?

Comment: Try `scala -classpath lib/*.jar -jar MyScalaJar.jar`.

Comment: It also doesn't work. same exception:
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)